# how add JTextField to Jpanel which have JButton

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jbutton, jtextfield

I have add JtextField line , but in the output only button shows. what i have miss , please write your answer with java code for clearence. Thanks!

```
 public JPanel createContentPane (){
JButton Button1
buttonPanel = new JPanel();
buttonPanel.setLayout(null);
buttonPanel.setLocation(10, 50);
buttonPanel.setSize(1370, 770);
totalGUI.add(buttonPanel);

    Button1 = new JButton("Button 1");
    Button1.setLocation(0, 0);
    Button1.setSize(120, 30);
    Button1.addActionListener(this);
    buttonPanel.add(Button1);

  JLabel l;
  l= new JLabel;
  JTextField a = new JTextField();
    a.setVisible(true);
    a.setLocation(1000,200);
    l.add(a);
}
```

This is the main method and createAndShowGUI

```
private  void createAndShowGUI() {


        JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("[=] JButton Scores! [=]");



        //Create and set up the content pane.
        ButtonExample_Extended demo = new ButtonExample_Extended();
        frame.setContentPane(demo.createContentPane());

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(1370, 770);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Schedule a job for the event-dispatching thread:
        //creating and showing this application's GUI.
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new ButtonExample_Extended().createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for somthing like that:

```
public JPanel createContentPane() {
    buttonPanel = new JPanel();
    buttonPanel.setLayout(null);
    buttonPanel.setLocation(10, 50);
    buttonPanel.setSize(1370, 770);

    JButton Button1 = new JButton("Button 1");
    Button1.setLocation(0, 0);
    Button1.setSize(120, 30);
    buttonPanel.add(Button1);

    JTextField a = new JTextField(20);
    a.setLocation(125, 0);
    a.setSize(120, 30);
    buttonPanel.add(a);

    return buttonPanel;
}
```

1) Try to use [LayoutManager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html) instead of `buttonPanel.setLayout(null);`, `setLocation()`, `setSize()`.

2) `a.setVisible(true);` here is not necessary, it's by default `true`.

3) You needn't to add your `JTextField` to `JLabel`. Add components to container like `JPanel`.

4)I recommend you to read [swing tutorial about components](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/index.html)

5) Post a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) in future.